# What normal form does Laravel's Eloquent use?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I've been learning laravel for the past couple of months, but I'm having trouble understanding Eloquent's relationships from a relational database standpoint.

For example, from this [laracsts video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/8):

Jeff creates a notes table that is defined as:

```
table notes
------------------------------------
| id | card_id | body | time_stamps|
------------------------------------
```

why wouldn't you define the notes table with two tables, so that the second table relates the cards table and the notes table.

Example:

```
table notes
--------------------------
| id | body | time_stamps|
--------------------------

table card_notes
---------------------
| note_id | card_id |
---------------------
```

Is this wrong, or am I overthinking this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: He would define two tables if one `Note` may belong to many `Card`s.\

Answer (score 2):

For one-to-many relationship pivot table will be just redundant. In this case you'll use many-to-many relationship for one-to-many one. Of course you can do this, but why would you want it?

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. I wasn't sure if normalizing the table would be beneficial, but I guess that's essential the entire reason for Eloquent.